# How do I convert a strongly typed DataTable to an untyped DataTable

Tags: c#, wcf, datatable, ado.net

I tried to send a strongly typed DataTable to a WCF service that was expecting an untyped DataTable with the same data.

However, I got an error because the serializer didn't know what to do with the extra properties.

How can I convert my strongly typed DataTable to its untyped equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** For a basic explanation of Strongly Typed vs. Untyped DataSets, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923418/strongly-typed-datasets-vs-weakly-typed-datasets).

This can be done with a simple merge command, like this:

```
// convert stringly typed DataTable "data" to a loosely-typed version of itself
var data_untyped = new DataTable(data.TableName, data.Namespace);
data_untyped.Merge(data);
```

The first (non-comment) line creates the new DataTable, copying the TableName and Namespace.

The last line copies the data, including the column definitions.