# How to read a value from mysql database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to be able to read a value (in this case an Group ID). All the topics and tutorials I've watched/read take the data and put it into a textbox.

I don't want to put it in a textbox in this case; I want to grab the Group ID and then say:

If Group ID = 4 then login

[image]

Here is an image of the database.

Basically, but none of the tutorials I watch or the multiple forums. None of them take a a value and say if value = 4 then login or do something else.

```vb
If text = "1" Then
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "server='ip of server'.; username=; password=; database="
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim member_group_id As String

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT * FROM `core_members` where name='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
        Query = "SELECT * FROM `nexus_licensekeys` where lkey_key='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While READER.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While
```

Here is what I have so far. I'm kind of new implementing mysql data with visual basic and only recently started to get into it. I'm not sure what comes next or how to even start with reading the group id etc.

As I said any help from here on out would be highly appreciated of how to read the group id and say if this group id = this number then do this or that. I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: Why do you `Query = "SELECT * FROM ...` and then another `Query = "SELECT * FROM ...` immediately after?

Comment: If you're only returning a single value then you can use the ExecuteScalar method. Refer to [This article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) The last paragraph specifically.

Comment: What happens if you put this into TextBox2 then run? `';drop table core_members;--`

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: That code you took from the web you said it puts the value into "textbox1" let's say right? And you don't want it to be in a textbox that's why you came asking the question? Change that part instead of textbox1.text = whatever, take that whatever and now you have the value you want.. btw your second query is replacing your first query, and why select * if you only want groupID? dim count as integer = 0, count += 1, you have to learn the language before asking questions, there's no way you have searched for an answer before coming here :)

Comment: @devcon Ok so first of all I am selecting because I am getting the members username and revcieving the license key name because I am allowing the user to login. The query I needed a new one for the license key because it was in a different place. I don't know whether you can do another select in the same query but I just made a new one. It doesn't repalce it it just adds another one. Now what I want to do is say if member is in group id 4 then they can log in. If the member is in group id 2 then they can't, however I still want to keep the login with the username and license key.

Comment: @Devcon and also I am tyring to learn the language (as I said before anyway I'm new to sql data stuff with visual basic but I'm stuck? And how do you learn? You learn by asking and getting information and I have searched otherwise I wouldn't be asking and I just don't search a ltitle bit. I mean I search a lot before resorting to asking.

Comment: @djv Well, I'm not sure if you can have two selects in the same query so I thought well I need another one because I need it to select from a different place, so I copied and paste the query and just replaced it to where I need it to select from. Works just fine how it is

Comment: @Blooberz no, the second assignment overwrites the first assignment. `SELECT * FROM core_members...` is never used in your example

Comment: yup exactly, query is a string here and when you say query = "abc" and then query = "def", and you print query you're going to get "def" no matter what

Comment: You probably won't do this, but you should look into an ORM like EntityFramework. It should solve most issues with your code such as improper disposal of resources, sql injection, and untyped datasets both in your question and @Mary's answer i.e. see [this answer about typing datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8890446/832052)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I divided the code into UI Sub, and Data Access Function that can return data to the UI. Your Event procedure code should be rather brief and the functions should have a single purpose.

Keep your database objects local to the method. This way you can have better control. The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

I leave it to you to add validation code. Checking for empty TextBox or no return of records.

I hope this serves as a quick introduction to using ADO.net. The take away is:

1. Use Parameters
2. Make sure connections are closed. (Using blocks)

```vb
Private ConnString As String = "server=ip of server; username=; password=; database="

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim GroupID As String = GetGroupID(TextBox1.Text)
    If GroupID = "4" Then
        'your code here
    End If
    Dim LocalTable As DataTable = GetLicenseKeysData(TextBox1.Text)
    'Get the count
    Dim RowCount As Integer = LocalTable.Rows.Count
    'Display the data
    DataGridView1.DataSource = LocalTable
End Sub

Private Function GetGroupID(InputName As String) As String
    'Are you sure member_group_id is a String? Sure looks like it should be an Integer
    Dim member_group_id As String = ""
    'You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection
    Using MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection(ConnString)
        'If you only need the value of one field Select just the field not *
        'ALWAYS use parameters. See comment by @djv concerning drop table
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT g_id FROM core_members where name= @Name")
            'The parameters are interperted by the server as a value and not executable code
            'so even if a malicious user entered "drop table" it would not be executed.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = InputName
            MysqlConn.Open()
            'ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row of the result set
            member_group_id = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
        End Using
    End Using
    Return member_group_id
End Function

Private Function GetLicenseKeysData(InputName As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConnString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `nexus_licensekeys` where lkey_key= @Name;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = InputName
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: @djv Thank you. Fixed it.